# jQuery: Trying to make animation happen every 3 seconds, not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
$("#gifttwo").on('click', function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#shuriken").removeClass("animated wobble").addClass("animated wobble");
    }, 3000);
});
```

*shuriken* is an image. it only happens once.. why isn't this working?

Comment: Removing and adding a class back-to-back like that will not result in anything happening in the view. The browser doesn't immediately start re-doing the layout when you add a class; it waits until it absolutely has to do the layout, or until the event loop expires.

Comment: ... and you can trigger the redraw by using a small timeout between removing the class, and adding it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off using [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
$("#gifttwo").on("click", function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#shuriken").toggleClass("animated wobble");
  }, 3000);
});
```